# Finding the mixed second partial derivative of $\cos (xy^2)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am finding the second partials of $f(x,y)=\cos (xy^2)$.
I have found $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ but I am stuck on how to find $f_{xy}$, could someone explain this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$f_x = -y^2 \sin \left(x y^2\right)$$

So, to find $f_{xy}$, we use the chain/product rule and have

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} (f_x) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} (-y^2 \sin \left(x y^2\right)) = -2 y \sin \left(x y^2\right)-2 x y^3 \cos \left(x y^2\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f_x = -y^2\sin(xy^2)$$

Now use product rule:

$$f_{xy} = -2y\sin(xy^2)-2xy^3\cos(xy^2)$$